# Eloquent query building complex query to get unique records searching for an ID in 2 different columns in same table

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm migrating a project to Laravel 4 and I am stuck with a quite complex query, which I'd like to migrate into a proper Eloquent query.

I have a table that contains chat messages, called `chat_messages` with a representing Model `Chatmessage`

The table contains a sender and a receipient column with a user id linking to the `users` table and `User` Model.

The query to get a list with all user IDs of all chat partners in raw SQL on the old version of the application is as follows:

```
$sql_allChatPartners = "SELECT DISTINCT chatPartner   
FROM ( SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT cm_receipient AS chatPartner, cm_sent_at
    FROM chat_messages WHERE cm_sender = '".$me->userID."'
    UNION
    SELECT cm_sender AS chatPartner, cm_sent_at
    FROM chat_messages WHERE cm_receipient = '".$me->userID."'
) whateva ORDER BY whateva.cm_sent_at DESC ) other";
```

Sorry for naming the "fake" tables whateva and other :-)

Could anyone put me in the right direction to do this with Eloquent Querybuilder?

It is important that I get the list of chatPartner IDs in the correct order, where the last chat message has been exchanged as first chatPartner. And the chatPartner where longest inactivity was in the chat as last entry.

This is what I got so far in my User Model...

```
public function allopenchats(){
 $asSender = Chatmessage::where('sender', $this->id)->select('receipient as chatPartner, created_at');
 $asBoth = Chatmessage::where('receipient', $this->id)->select('sender as chatPartner, created_at')
              ->union($asSender)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
}
```

I renamed the columns `cm_receipient` to `receipient`, `cm_sender` to `sender` and `sent_at` to `created_at` in the new database for the new version

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to Vitalik_74, I wouldn't have come that far without him.
Here is now the final query, although its not in ORM, but it is working fine and gives me the result I need.

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * 
            FROM (
               SELECT IF( receipient =  '".$this->id."', sender, IF( sender =  '".$this->id."', receipient,  'no' ) ) AS chatPartner, created_at
               FROM chatmessages
               WHERE receipient =  '".$this->id."'
               OR sender =  '".$this->id."'
               HAVING chatPartner !=  'no'
               ORDER BY created_at DESC
            )whateva
            GROUP BY whateva.chatPartner
            ORDER BY whateva.created_at DESC");
```

if there is someone out there who can do this query with the Laravel Query Builder, I would be happy to see it. For now I'll leave it like this.

Answer (score 1):

You sql may change to:

```
    SELECT IF (cm_receipient = '10', cm_sender, IF (cm_sender = '10',cm_receipient, 'no')) AS chatPartner, cm_sent_at
FROM chat_messages
WHERE cm_receipient = '10' OR cm_sender = '10'
GROUP BY chatPartner
HAVING chatPartner != 'no'
```

order by cm_sent_at DESC

In orm:

```
Chatmessage::where('sender','=',$this->id)
    ->orWhere('receipient','=',$this->id)
    ->select(DB::raw('IF (receipient = '.$this->id.', sender, IF (sender = '.$this->id.',receipient, 'no' )) AS chatPartner'), 'created_at')
    ->groupBy('chatPartner')
    ->having('chatPartner', '!=', 'no')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it's very important to consider the column created_at, I need the result to be ordered by the latest entry of each chat. This forced me to do double nesting in the initial raw query... Took me very loong to figure that one out.

Comment: This works almost, but the chatPartners are ordered by the first message exchanged instead of the last message exchanged.

I tried also my initial raw query as 
`$result = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT chatPartner
   FROM ( SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT receipient AS chatPartner, created_at
       FROM chatmessages WHERE sender = '".$this->id."'
       UNION
       SELECT sender AS chatPartner, created_at
       FROM chatmessages WHERE receipient = '".$this->id."'
   ) whateva ORDER BY whateva.created_at ) other"));`
and I have the same problem there

Comment: I remember creating the initial query using GROUP BY which took the first match instead of the last match for the timestamp... so I had to work around this...

Comment: Ok. You should use `DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT chatPartner   
FROM ( SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT IF (receipient = '".$this->id."', sender, IF (sender = '".$this->id."',receipient, 'no')) AS chatPartner, created_at
FROM chatmessages 
WHERE receipient = '".$this->id."' OR sender = '".$this->id."'
HAVING chatPartner != 'no'
) whateva ORDER BY whateva.created_at DESC ) other");` I don't know a way to use ORM query with sub-query (that get order with `created_at`).

Comment: Thanks very much, but I still have the same issue, that the order is wrong, it's still ordering by the first message exchanged and not the by tthe last message exchanged, as I need it... 
I don't understand, as it was working fine on the old system / server

Comment: In new server field `created_at` is `int (11)`? In old server field `cm_sent_at` is `int (11)`? May be they different.

Comment: They are datetime fields in both databases / servers with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format